# How do different languages convey shades of meaning as English does with stress?

Tags: emphasis

Browsing this site recently, I noticed a lot of discussion, not to say bickering, about whether some languages are more expressive or nuanced than others.  It reminded me of a question I had in my head long before I discovered Stack Exchange: how do languages that don't use stress for emphasis convey shades of meaning?  An example [paraphrased from memory] from an almost-forgotten BBC radio show :-

Patient: I was at an orgy the other night ...

Doctor: An *orgy* you say?

Patient: Yes, I *live* in Purley.

Now, if the patient had said, "Yes, I live in *Purley*", it would have been mildly funny, suggesting that Purley is a place where orgies often happen.  But by stressing the word 'live', he's saying that it's *understood* that Purley is the place for orgies, but because he *lives* there, it's easy for him to get 
to them.

My question is, Can this nuance be expressed in other languages, whether by emphasis or by re-phrasing?  I know, for example, that in French, "I live in *Purley* might be expressed as something like "C'est a Purley que j'habite", but I can't see how you'd exactly translate "I *live* in Purley".
[By the way, I asked this question of a multi-lingual EU 
translator, and he couldn't get past finding different countries' equivalents of Purley.]

Comment: There are language specific nuances and cultural aspects that are simply not translatable. What is funny for  Japanese may be just boring to a Portuguese for instance. What point do you want to make with your question?

Comment: @Josh61, My point is, trying not to be Anglocentric and because I've read here and there that all languages can be equally expressive, how do other languages do it?

Comment: And actually, one can achieve rather different meanings in English too, without italicizing or relying on intonation alone. Consider: "I believe you."  "I do believe you." "It's you I believe."  "It's me who believes you."

Comment: Good, @anemone.  I'd be interested, all the same, in seeing some examples of what other languages do.  And as an aside, when I learned French in the 1960s, I was taught that stress-emphasis wasn't used.  But watching "La Retour de Martin Guerre", I noticed Gerard Depardieu insisting, "C'est MON village, c'est MA femme...".  Could any French-speaker comment on this?

Comment: By the way, if you are particularly interested in French, there is a site dedicated to the French language here at SE.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [Wikipedia article on **topic and comment** in a sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic%E2%80%93comment) that strives to explain how various languages devise to stress the focal element in a sentence.

I quote the initial passage:

> In linguistics, the topic, or theme, of a sentence is what is being talked about, and the comment (rheme or focus) is what is being said about the topic. That the information structure of a clause is divided in this way is generally agreed on, but the boundary between topic/theme depends on grammatical theory.

The topic-comment distinction was studied in great level of detail by the [Prague Linguistic Circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prague_school), presumably in connection to various shades of meaning one can achieve in Czech by opting for different word orders in a sentence. (Czech, as a richly inflected language, offers a good deal of freedom to the speaker as regards word order.)

Comment: Thank-you @Anenome.  I've just skimmed that article, and I'll return to it at length. +1